# Fan or just bad placement?

Tags: fan

My laptop shutdown four times when it was on the table. It had an error about thermal shutdown and being 90d. When I held it, nothing. For five minutes. Then I placed it on a pile of books so far and I'm typing now. No shutdown so far. What's the issue?

Comment: Is there anything on the table you had it sitting on (like a doily)? What material is the table made from? If you put it back on the table in the same spot, does it overheat again? When was the last time you cleaned dust out of the notebook? Is the fan spinning as expected?

Comment: The table has a cloth on it with a plastic hard cover. Kind of like.... a plasted paper cloth. Can't explain it.

Comment: I mean a table cover with plastic over it

Comment: Ensure you have clear airflow under the laptop at all times. now that aside, temperature can be a runtime condition, so watch out for programs over using the CPU for extended periods. You should probably also check that your CPU cooling is effective. CPUs heat up very quickly, and cool down very quickly as well, if your fans and heatsink are working correctly. try monitoring your temperatures with Speedfan or CoreTemp (watch out for ad-ware laden installers) to monitor your temperature. try to heat it up running an intense program, and then see how long it takes to cool down after exiting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not enough ventilation, so your system is overheating.

When using your laptop, place two similarly sized objects under the back two corners.  That should really help.  They make something called "Cool Balls" that are little half-spheres that do this.  I don't think they allow linking to products here, but they are easy to find.  Or you can buy two erasers and place them under the back corners.  They will lift up the back (allowing airflow) and provide resistance to the system sliding away.

I also recommend purchasing a laptop stand with a fan in it.  Make sure it blows in the correct direction to complement the cooling of your system.